# How to filter Fancybox lightbox by class so that only a certain class is included in the group (Squarespace)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox, squarespace

I have two galleries on a page, one of full-sized images, and one of thumbnails that link to other galleries. I'm using a code injection on Squarespace. I'm trying to have only the full-sized images show up in the lightbox as a group, but no matter how many filters I try, fancybox is pulling all the images on the page into the lightboxed group. I'm wrapping anchor tags around the thumbnail images as well, because even if they don't have anchor tags wrapped around them, the thumbnail images are still being added to the lightbox gallery. The large images are descendants of the div with id of "projectPages" while the thumbnails are in a lower div as descendants of a div with an id of "projectThumbs."

Here's my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  //wrap anchor tags around large images and add fancybox class
  $('div#projectPages img').wrap('<a class="fancybox" data-fancybox-group="group1"  style="display:block"></a>');

  //wrap anchor tags around thumbnail images and add dontShow class
  $('div#projectThumbs img').wrap('<a class="dontShow" style="display:block"></a>');

  //give the anchor tag the same href attr as the img's src attr
  $("div#projectPages div.image a > img").each(function() {
    $(this).parent().attr("href", $(this).data('src'));
  });

});

//call fancybox on fancybox class
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".fancybox").fancybox({

  });
});
```

Comment: `even if they don't have anchor tags wrapped around them, the thumbnail images are still being added to the lightbox gallery` ... it sounds like you have somewhere in your code `$("img").fancybox()` or `$("div img").fancybox()` ... or the `img` tags have a `.fancybox` class

Answer (score 0):

If you want to only include elements with a specific class inside the fancy box, can you not just target that class in your selector?

```
$('#projectPages .hasClass img').wrap();
```